# MemoryError when using very large ClassificationDataSets in PyBrain

Tags: python, numpy, pybrain

https://gist.github.com/Skyyrunner/8317943

The above gist link has the relevant code & console output. The dataset I am trying to feed to ClassificationDataSet has a dimension of 860 in, 1 out, and is roughly 470k elements of ints, mostly 0s. The problem is no matter how I try to split it up into multiple lists, it still crashes with the Memory Error appended in the gist. Is there a good way to solve this problem?